# JApplication::getCfg deprecated

Tags: joomla-3.x, deprecated

What is the newer syntax to replace the deprecated `JApplication::getCfg()`?

The docs don't specify the replacement in the deprecation notice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get the config settings for you.

```
$config = JFactory::getConfig();
echo 'Site name is ' . $config->get( 'sitename' );
```

Answer (score 0):

That's odd, it does in version 3.4.8, the syntax is the same but the name of the method has been shortened to just `get` If you jump to the original class in your IDE this is the old `getCfg()` method:

```
 /**
 * Gets a configuration value.
 *
 * @param   string  $varname  The name of the value to get.
 * @param   string  $default  Default value to return
 *
 * @return  mixed  The user state.
 *
 * @since   3.2
 * @deprecated  4.0  Use get() instead
 */
public function getCfg($varname, $default = null)
{
    return $this->get($varname, $default);
}
```

As you can see `getCfg('someVarName')` can simply be replaced with `get('someVarName')`.